# Django - how to style the placeholder of a form field?

Tags: django, forms, widget, styles, registration

Ok, so I've installed the django-registration app and, for the register feature, I have added a widget for the email to make a placeholder:

```
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"),
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email'}))
```

I prefer to use a placeholder, instead of a label.

Now, my question is: how to style the placeholder? add some colour, change the placeholder size and font etc
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: You can add class='somestyleclass' in attrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"),
                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email', 'class':'your_css_code'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with this as well, but then I realized that you don't want to style the placeholder within your Django form. Just add the following css to your style sheet and you'll be good to go.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```